# Haskell How to Create a Word8?

Tags: string, haskell, bytestring

I want to write a simple function which splits a `ByteString` into `[ByteString]` using `'\n'` as the delimiter.  My attempt:

```
import Data.ByteString

listize :: ByteString -> [ByteString]
listize xs = Data.ByteString.splitWith (=='\n') xs
```

This throws an error because `'\n'` is a `Char` rather than a `Word8`, which is what [`Data.ByteString.splitWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#v:splitWith) is expecting.

How do I turn this simple character into a `Word8` that `ByteString` will play with?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could just use the numeric literal `10`, but if you want to convert the character literal you can use `fromIntegral (ord '\n')` (the `fromIntegral` is required to convert the `Int` that `ord` returns into a `Word8`). You'll have to import `Data.Char` for `ord`.

You could also import [`Data.ByteString.Char8`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html), which offers functions for using `Char` instead of `Word8` on the same `ByteString` data type. (Indeed, it has a [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v%3alines) function that does exactly what you want.) However, this is generally *not* recommended, as `ByteString`s *don't* store Unicode codepoints (which is what `Char` represents) but instead raw octets (i.e. `Word8`s).

If you're processing textual data, you should consider using [`Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) instead of `ByteString`.

Comment: Oh, wow.  Excellent.  I will have to dig into character representations, I guess.  I have no idea what the numerical literals for the characters are.  Is there a list of them somewhere?

Comment: I am writing a program that will parse protein database files, which contain strings, integers, and doubles.  The strings will mostly be used to identify the right items out of a list, whereas the ints and doubles will be used in math operations.  I am not sure what class I should use for this.

Comment: You could use `ord` in GHCi to find out the codepoint numbers of characters :) I generally get Unicode data from [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm); the [Basic Latin](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/basic_latin/index.htm) block contains the 128 codepoints inherited from ASCII.

Comment: As for the appropriate type for your program, it depends on the specific format and what you're doing, but if they don't contain any binary data, then `Text` would work fine. However, if the strings are always pure ASCII, and you're processing a large amount of data, then `ByteString` is likely to be faster.

Comment: Yes, the files are strictly ASCII, and performance is the goal.  Thank you.

Comment: How do I create a Word8 now?