# Haskell: Function that converts Char to Word8

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find a function that converts a Char to a Word8, and another that converts it back. I've looked on Hoogle and there are no functions of type Char -> Word8. I want to do this because Word8 has an instance of the Num class, and I would be able  to add numbers to them to change them to another number. For example, my function would look something like:

```
shift :: Char -> Int -> Char
shift c x = toChar $ (toWord8 c) + x
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966439/haskell-how-to-create-a-word8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `fromEnum` and `toEnum` to go via `Int` instead. This has the added benefit of also supporting Unicode.

```
> toEnum (fromEnum 'a' + 3) :: Char
'd'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found these using FP Complete's Hoogle: http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.7/20131212-1/utf8-string/Codec-Binary-UTF8-String.html#v:encodeChar

A `Char` doesn't necessarily contain only one byte, so the conversions you're describing could lose information. Would these functions work instead?